# I can run my project in xampp (localhost) but I cannot run when am trying run in another computer even after configuring

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xampp

```
<?php
session_start();

define("HOST","localhost");
define("USER","root");
define("PASS","");
define("DB","project_inv");

define("DOMAIN","http://localhost/      
inv_project/public_html/dont");
?>
```

Database:

```
<?php

class Database
{
    private $con;

    public function connect(){
        include_once("constants.php");
        $this->con = new Mysqli(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
        if ($this->con) {
            return $this->con;
        }
        return "DATABASE_CONNECTION_FAIL";
    }
}

//$db = new Database();
//$db->connect();

?>
```

JavaScript Validation Part: It comes here and keeps on loading when am trying to take from ip, e.g. `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/inv_project/public_html/dont/`

//For Login Part

```
$("#form_login").on("submit",function(){
        var email = $("#log_email");
        var pass = $("#log_password");
        var status = false;
        if (email.val() == "") {
            email.addClass("border-danger");
            $("#e_error").html("<span class='text-danger'>Please Enter Email Address</span>");
            status = false;
        }else{
            email.removeClass("border-danger");
            $("#e_error").html("");
            status = true;
        }
        if (pass.val() == "") {
            pass.addClass("border-danger");
            $("#p_error").html("<span class='text-danger'>Please Enter Password</span>");
            status = false;
        }else{
            pass.removeClass("border-danger");
            $("#p_error").html("");
            status = true;
        }
        if (status) {
            $(".overlay").show();
            $.ajax({
                url : DOMAIN+"/includes/process.php",
                method : "POST",
                data : $("#form_login").serialize(),
                success : function(data){
                    if (data == "NOT_REGISTERD") {
                        $(".overlay").hide();
                        email.addClass("border-danger");
                        $("#e_error").html("<span class='text-danger'>It seems like you are not registered</span>");
                    }else if(data == "PASSWORD_NOT_MATCHED"){
                        $(".overlay").hide();
                        pass.addClass("border-danger");
                        $("#p_error").html("<span class='text-danger'>Please Enter Correct Password</span>");
                        status = false;
                    }else{
                        $(".overlay").hide();
                        console.log(data);
                        window.location.href = DOMAIN+"/dashboard.php";
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    })
```

While am trying to run from other computer it displays the design and content of the page but it is not validating but when am trying locally it works fine.

Comment: Do you get some error?

Comment: `url : DOMAIN+"/includes/process.php",` is incorrect, you should use your IP address since you're trying to access your computer from another computer.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't define DOMAIN as "localhost". This will cause errors, while calling the page from other computers.

Localhost means always the computer the script is running on. Using this in a JavaScript the reference to the server is lost and it tries to connect/forward to the client-computer - with no success. This works on the first computer, because this might be the server.